# Ionic 5 / Angular routing not working when navigating via URL

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, url-routing, ionic5

**Ionic router not navigating into sub URL via new tab**

I have tried various different configurations of the ionic router, It work when navigating with the buttons in the application but if I try to copy and past URL in a new tab it does not work.

**Example**:

localhost:8100 -> [button click] -> localhost:8100/view/auto : **[WORKS]**

localhost:8100/view/auto : **[NOT WORKING]**

I have my routes set up as the following:
App module -> Home Module -> View Module -> Auto Component

**[Console Image]**: Here is the error i get in console when reloading the page.

[image: ERROR]

Here are the images of the route arrays:

**[App Module]**:

HTML:

```html
<ion-app>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

ROUTER:
[image: App Router Module]

**[Home Module]**

HTML:

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-router-outlet overflow-scroll="true"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

ROUTER:
[image: Home router module]

**[View Module]**

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-router-outlet overflow-scroll="true"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

ROUTER:
[image: View Router Module]

Comment: Include your code as text rather than images so it can be copied and searched.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was in index.html.
I need to change:

```
base href="./" />
```

to

```
<base href="/" />
```